# Apache NIFI custom processor gives error "cannot find suitable driver"

Tags: java, jdbc, mariadb, apache-nifi, apache-commons-dbcp

I have created a nifi processor that is supposed to read something from a database and put the result in an attribute. The code is very trivial, just creating a simple JDBC connection.

```java
private Connection getDatabaseConnection(ProcessContext context){
    if(databaseConnection == null) {
        try {
            String url = createJDBCUrl(context);
            databaseConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,
                   context.getProperty(DB_USER_NAME).getValue(),
                   context.getProperty(DB_PASSWORD).getValue());
        } catch (Exception throwables) {
            throwables.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return databaseConnection;
}

private String createJDBCUrl(ProcessContext context) {
    String ip = context.getProperty(DB_IP).getValue();
    String port = context.getProperty(DB_PORT).getValue();
    String dbName = context.getProperty(DB_NAME).getValue();
    return "jdbc:mariadb://" + ip + ":" + port + "/" + dbName;
}
```

I get this error:

```
No suitable driver found for jdbc:mariadb://databaste-ip:3306/database-name
```

I have tried putting `mysql-connector-java-5.1.49` file in nifi lib folder but no luck. Also I put the file in resource folder to bundle the driver with the processor but no success as well.
Also I wrote the processor differently and used BasicDataSource from Apache commons-dbcp, so I could define where the driver file is located but again I got an error:

```
Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' for connect URL 'jdbc:mariadb://database-ip:3306/database-name'
```

Comment: If you're using the `jdbc:mariadb:` protocol, then you should use the MariaDB Connector, not the MySQL Connector/J driver. The MySQL Connector/J driver only knows about the `jdbc:mysql:` protocol.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thanks for the tip, though I use this for my other applications, and for simple crud queries it works!

Comment: That really does not work with the MySQL Connector/J driver in combination with `jdbc:mariadb:`. Either you then also have the MariaDB Connector on the classpath, or you're using `jdbc:mysql:` protocol.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel my bad, I was thinking about the connector jar file.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel as you said it worked and solved the problem, thanks. Maybe you can add your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the `jdbc:mariadb:` protocol, then you should use the [MariaDB Connector/J](https://downloads.mariadb.org/connector-java/+releases/), not the MySQL Connector/J driver. The MySQL Connector/J driver only knows about the `jdbc:mysql:` protocol.

Or alternatively, if you want to continue to use MySQL Connector/J, then you should use protocol `jdbc:mysql:`. However, given MySQL and MariaDB are - I assume - diverging, it is better to use the driver specifically written for MariaDB.